# Проблема с dropdown bootstrap

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, angularjs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажитии на кнопку с выпадающим списком у меня выпадающий список прячется, и нужно скроллить вручную, как сделать выпадающий список видимым? 
jQuery сразу исключаю, потому что проект на angular. Скролл сейчас на самом низу. Всем спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap сам не понимает хватит ли ему места снизу для отображения контента на экране. Нужно самостоятельно вычислять размеры и добавлять class `dropup` к элементу с которого происходит выпадание.